# How can I arrange images horizontally with text in the same space?

Tags: graphics, floats, wrapfigure

Edit:
I got it to look how I want with the following code but I don't think its the proper way.

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \flushleft
        \includegraphics[height=1.4cm]{Logo_file1}
        \newline
        \newline
        Official company of a thing,\\
        In a place somewhere\\
        Bla bla bla Lorem Ipsum!
    \end{minipage}
    %\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \flushright
        \includegraphics[height=4.0cm]{Logo_file2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

---

So I got the following bit of code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[height=1.4cm]{Logo_file1}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[height=4.0cm]{Logo_file2}
\end{figure}
Official company of a thing,\\
In a place somewhere\\
Bla bla bla Lorem Ipsum!
```

But this causes the first image to be at the bottom of the "box" that these images are in.
I need this image to sit at the top flush with the top of the second image like in this picture:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.  `valign=t` option provided if you load `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`  might help with the vertical alginment of the images.

Answer (score 2):

The `adjustbox` package defines a `valign` key:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \color{Tomato} \includegraphics[height=1.4cm, valign=t]{Logo_file1}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[height=4.0cm, valign=t]{Logo_file2}
\end{figure}
\noindent
Official company of a thing,\\
In a place somewhere\\
Bla bla bla Lorem Ipsum!

\end{document}
```

[image]